# What is the proper method to go about finding the order of growth for this function?

Tags: big-o

2^n + 6n^2 + 3n

I guess it's just O(2^n), using the highest order term, but what is the formal approach to go about proving this?

Comment: I miss Discrete Mathematics.  I failed it the first time.

Comment: nah, not homework. Just confused about various methods to get mathematical proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove that `2^n + n^2 + n = O(2^n)` by using limits at infinity.  Specifically, `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if `lim (n->inf.) f(n)/g(n)` is finite.

```
lim (n->inf.) ((2^n + n^2 + n) / 2^n)
```

Since you have inf/inf, an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), you can use [L'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and differentiate the numerator and the denominator until you get something you can work with:

```
lim (n->inf.) ((ln(2)*2^n + 2n + 1) / (ln(2)*2^n))
lim (n->inf.) ((ln(2)*ln(2)*2^n + 2) / (ln(2)*ln(2)*2^n))
lim (n->inf.) ((ln(2)*ln(2)*ln(2)*2^n) / (ln(2)*ln(2)*ln(2)*2^n))
```

The limit is 1, so `2^n + n^2 + n` is indeed `O(2^n)`.

Comment: Is this not for finding small-oh? x__x

Also, is there an alternative method that, say, uses only inequalities?

Comment: Little o is different; that's where lim (n->inf.) f(n)/g(n) = 0, meaning g(n) grows faster than f(n) (e.g. n is o(n^2) since n^2 grows faster than n).  You could use inequalities to show that f(n) <= M*g(n) for some real number M in order to prove that f(n) is O(g(n)).

Comment: Ah ok, ok. And in the inequality method, we can only proceed by trial and error to get the constants, since we need to get proper values for both M AND n-knot?

Comment: I guess it would be essentially trial and error, but it would be fairly simple to make good guesses with similar enough functions.

Answer (score 3):

Please see:

[Big O Notation Homework--Code Fragment Algorithm Analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216796/big-o-notation-homework-code-fragment-algorithm-analysis)

[Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

[Can someone please explain the difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/can-someone-please-explain-the-difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation/1364491)

[Big-O for Eight Year Olds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds) (not meant to be insulting)