# Calculating a Theta (Tight Bound) Estimation

Tags: big-o

I was just wondering if someone could explain this a little to me. I want to know how to calculate an estimate for a Theta function using the integrals or the truncate-and-bound method.

For Example how would you calculate:

> ∑<sub>i=1..n</sub> i⋅sqrt(i)+1

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:

- [Can someone explain how Big-Oh works with Summations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377282/can-someone-explain-how-big-oh-works-with-summations)
- [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on)
- [Big O Notation Homework--Code Fragment Algorithm Analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216796/big-o-notation-homework-code-fragment-algorithm-analysis)